# How can we check file pointer is assigned or not in delphi?

Tags: file, delphi

In delphi we can create file pointer to read and write the strings into the file. In my project i have to create the file pointer if it is not assigned.

Please share the thoughts to achieve it.

```
AssignFile(FilePtr, 'File1.txt');
Rewrite(FilePtr);
closeFile(FilePtr);
```

Comment: Actually, `FilePtr` isn't a pointer but a record.

Comment: What you are looking for is a `Boolean` variable. Alternatively you could move into the 21st Century and move on from legacy Pascal I/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that FilePtr is a TextFile, since you're writing to a .TXT file.

If FilePtr is a member of a CLASS, it has been zeroed from start. If it is a global variable, it has as well. If it is a local variable, you'll need to do so yourself at the beginning of the method defining it:

```
TTextRec(FilePtr).Handle:=0;
```

You can then check if it has already been assigned to a file with this:

```
IF TTextRec(FilePtr).Handle=0 THEN BEGIN
  AssignFile(FilePtr,'File1.txt');
  Rewrite(FilePtr)
END;
```

When you close it, you must also add this line:

```
CloseFile(FilePtr);
TTextRec(FilePtr).Handle:=0;
```

If your FilePtr is a FILE and not a TextFile, replace TTextRec with TFileRec instead.

Comment: Thanks Heartware. This is useful solution.